# Not able to identify element for the below code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, label, uilabel, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried multiple ways to identify accessories element in bottom but not successful

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-li-id='accessories']"));
```

[image]

Comment: Try to implement [Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to be able to click the radio button contained by that list item?

Comment: My goal is to click on Accessories but it is not a radio button.i tried below code as well but not successful                                                     
     WebElement accessories = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='product-filters filters']//div/ul/li[2]label[text()='Accessories']")));

Comment: Note that in your XPath there is no slash between `li[2]` and `label`: `.../li[2]label...` -> `.../li[2]/label....`

Comment: @Thota Are you trying to click to the label?

Comment: @ Sers: under product category i have Medical cannabis and accessories by default page will land in medical cannabis and i want to click on accesories. i tried multiple ways like below

Comment: @Sers: ("//*[@class='product-filters filters']//div/ul/li[2]label[text()='Accessories']")
//(By.cssSelector("//*[@class='product-filters.filters']//div/ul/li[2]/label[text()='Accessories']") //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='accessories']"));
 //(By.xpath("//ul[@class='filterCategory']/li[2]"));
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement accessories = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='filterCategory']/li[2]"));
   Actions builder = new Actions (driver);
   Action seriesofActions = builder
     .moveToElement(accessories)
     .click()
     .build();

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with code you use and error you got. Also try code below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// 1. Click to li element
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li[data-li-id='accessories']")))
        .click();

//Or 2. Click to radio button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("input#accessories")))
        .click();

//Or 3. If radio button not visible and above code not worked, try click with javascript like below
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.id("input#accessories")));
```

Also problem can be loading elements that overlay you `Accessories` or page not loaded completely. You can debug to check loading problems.

Comment: The below code worked fine  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='accessories']//parent::li[@data-li-id='accessories']//label[@for='accessories']")).click();    Thanks all for your time